# Programs with feedback?

Tags: algorithms, computability, dynamic-programming, recursion

Suppose we have a program like this:

```
def feedback(number):
    final(number) 
def final(number):
    if number=2 or number=4:
       print(number)
    else:
       feedback(number/2)
```

which is self referential in a way how can we predict the output of such programs? Do we have to brute force the result or is there a clever way to think about it?

Comment: Please state the question more clearly. Currently, I can't even parse it. Even if I could, I suspect that the question wouldn't be answerable until you define all the terms (e.g. what "model such a program" means).

Comment: @Dmitry Editted.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "predict the output of such functions".  What are the requirements?  What's wrong with just running the function and seeing what it outputs?  Are you asking for an algorithm that always terminates, to test whether it terminates, and if it does terminate, output what it outputs, and if it doesn't terminate, output that it doesn't terminate?

Comment: @D.W. we can predict the output of a recursive program by beginning our analysis from the end then work backwards. Can we predict with the same way the output of a program as stated in the question?

Comment: What you present has been described as *indirect recursion*. (And, as `feedback()` passes its parameter unmodified, a trivial/redundant one.) There is no program, just function definitions - with an implicit `return None`.

Comment: @greybeard obviously the function feedback is called by the command line of the Python environment. Also I'm more interested in what is printed in the output I know it returns None since neither feedback or finals return any value.

Comment: Lacking [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring), the purpose of the functions is anybody's guess. Neither *the Python environment command line* nor any other I'd care to be aware of will call anything on its own. Try it out: There are online/web Python environments should you not want to run your own.

Comment: My Python IDLE Shell can call any function from a .py file.:shrug:

Answer (score 0):

The program you show has no output. It defined two functions called `feedback` and `final`, and does nothing after that.

You probably meant to ask what happens if we *call* `final` with a given number? This can be analyzed quite easily, I suggest you do it as a useful exercise. Draw a table for values $n = \ldots, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots$ and for each $n$ determine what $\mathtt{final}(n)$ does. (Of course, you should actually run your code to see what it does.) Can you spot any patterns?